# Icon not loaded in firefox

Tags: jsp, firefox, jakarta-ee, html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/iconName.ico"/>
```

I am using the above line of code to load icon in my webpage.
It is woking properly with IE and Chrome but not working with firefox,
Can please any one tell me or suggest what i am doing wrong?
Or how can i overcome with above issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try few things

- put `iconName.ico` into root folder and rename it to `favicon.ico`
- make sure it's a PNG file or it's have correct `image/x-icon` MIME type